# redux reducer returned undefined handling

Tags: redux, reducers

My reducers like:

```
const initialState = [
  {
    fname: null,
    lname: false,
  }
]

export default function login(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      console.log("actions")
      console.log(action)
      console.log("reducers")
        return 
        [{
          fname: action.fname,
          lname: action.lname,
          }]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Here I am getting action object with `fname` and `lname` but this is giving me error saying .. `Uncaught Error: Reducer "login" returned undefined handling "LOGIN". To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state.`

Why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
 return
 [
```

To:

```
 return [
```

Because first is like `return;` (js adds `;` at the end of line)

Answer (score 0):

or

```
    ...
    console.log("reducers")
            return([{
                 fname: action.fname,
                 lname: action.lname,
              }])

  //example 
  function getPerson(){
    return([{
              fname: 'jay',
              lname: 'dawg'
          }])
  }

 console.log(getPerson()[0].lname) // "dawg"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was happening because I forgot to make the action call asynchronous `async`

```
export const asyncFetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = *await* axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/current_user');
  dispatch({ type: ASYNC_FETCH_USER, auth: response.data });
};
```